# Parsing Text Out of Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a quick question in regards to using only formula to parse texts out of a cell and group them together.

Here is what I have:

```
AX_BY_CZ_NP [1234]
```

I was able to get everything in with the exception of NP

Here are my formulas for BY, CZ, and I am currently stuck on the last bits of NZ

```
BY - =MID(A1, FIND("_",A1) + 1, FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1) - FIND("_",A1) - 1)

CZ - =MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1+(FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)-FIND("_",A1)),FIND("_", A1, FIND("_", A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)+1)-FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)-1)

NP - =MID(A9,FIND("_",A1,(FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)-FIND("_",A1))+FIND("_", A1, FIND("_", A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)+1)-FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)-1)+1, ????)
```

My brain is fried at this point and have no idea how to get more complicated and map everything out.

If you know the final part for CZ please help!

Comment: What is the final output you want?

Comment: final output to have each part dynamically parsed into 5 different cells

Answer (score 0):

Instead of horrible string formulas all nested up, you can do this quickly and painlessly with a UDF:

Go to your VBE (Ctrl+F11), make a new module, and paste this in:

```
 Function strtok(strIn As String, strDelim As String, intPos As Integer) As String
   'take in a string, split by delimiter, and return position
   strtok = Split(strIn, strDelim)(intPos - 1)
 End Function
```

Then in your workbook you can use this new `strtok()` formula:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","_"),"_",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

Put it in the first column then drag/copy across.

[image]